# Deploy Java Spring Boot Services to Production on EC2 Server

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, amazon-ec2

I'm currently new to deployment with Java and getting confused with jar and war.
If someone can clear my couple of questions below

Do I need to convert my jar (Java spring services) to war and deploy on Jboss/Tomcat? or I should copy my jar on prod server and run java -jar "jar name" with nohup.

What should be the ideal production deployment approach?

It's an enterprise level application.
Can someone please help me how do I deploy jar app in EC2 production server.

Comment: No, you need not. Yes, you could. Create a systemd daemon definition and timer to run the app, this is better than nohup

Comment: What's systemd daemon definition

Comment: You should not forget that EC2 instances need to be considered shortlived, you should automate the deployment

Comment: @Marged can you explain me lil more please ?

Answer (score 2):

Spring boot comes with an internal tomcat. So you do not need to deploy it inside a tomcat and neither do you need to convert it to a war.

You can just run it using the java - jar "jar name" command

Comment: But is it recommended in production deployment? Plus using jenkins if I want to do Continuous Deployment and with each commit I need to kill the existing port where app is running and restart with the command java - jar "jar name".

Comment: I have created a systemd service to start and stop my applications. So i just have to do systemctl start or systemctl stop

Comment: Can you help me with the systemd service file ?

Comment: Refer this link. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-systemctl-to-manage-systemd-services-and-units